# Splitting an array before adding to combo list

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, split

I have a JSON object that returns several key value pairs. One of which is a Languages key and this contains comma separated values e.g "English, Hindi,French" etc

I'm trying to split the array before adding it to a combo list, but everything I try fails. Can anybody help, please?

```
$('#combolist-languages').html(function () {

            var ret = '<option value="-1" selected>Select language_</option>',
                u = user.slice(),
                arr = [];

            (function get() {
                if (u.length) {
                    var v = u.shift();
                    if ($.inArray(v.Languages, arr) == -1) {

                        arr.push(v.Languages);
                        ret += '<option value="">' + v.Languages + '</option>';
                    }
                    get();
                }
            }());

            return ret;
        });
```

I'm just not sure where to put the split function. Thanks!

Comment: What does `v.Languages` contains?

Answer (score 1):

What about that?

```
var lang = 'English,Hindi,French';
var html = '<option value="-1" selected>Select language_</option>';
html += '<option value="">';
html += lang.split(',').join('</option><option value="">');
html += '</option>';
$('#combolist-languages').html(html);
```

Setting a value for each option with [`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) :

```
var lang = 'English,Hindi,French';
var html = '<option value="-1" selected>Select language_</option>';
$('#combolist-languages').html(
    html + jQuery.map(lang.split(','), function (text, value) {
        return '<option value="' + value + '">' + text + '</option>';
    })
);
```